# Transition error with translate CSS

Tags: css, animation, transition

I've already done a question about transition, but this time I have to do something a lot harder, and I have got one more time a problem with transition, honestly I have no idea about why it won't work, anyway.
I made some king a "bar", anyway something like an interface, basically is button with a plus. When you hover the pointer on the button, it will go up and show other element, with the transition.
When I hover out the transition work only for the button with the plus (trigger1) but not for the other hyperlink. Why?

Here the code:
html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Interface Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/interface.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="trigger">
        <div class="div">
            <center>
            <span class="text">+</span>
            </center>
        </div>
            <a class="element" href="#"></a>
            <a class="element2" href="#"></a>
            <a class="element3" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
.div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background: black;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    visibility: visible;
}
.trigger:hover .div {
    transform: translate(0px, -200px) rotate(45deg);
}
.trigger {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    border-radius: 50%
}
.element {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background: indigo;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.trigger:hover .element {
    transform: translate(0px, -50px);
    visibility: visible;
}
.element2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background: yellow;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.trigger:hover .element2 {
    transform: translate(0px, -100px);
    visibility: visible;
}
.element3 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background: blue;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.trigger:hover .element3 {
    transform: translate(0px, -150px);
    visibility: visible;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    top:
}
```

Thank's a lot for the help!

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evaOVO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you set `visibility: hidden` on the elements when your `.trigger` element is not being hovered.  It looks like they're not transitioning, but in reality, they're just disappearing.

Comment: Sorry, i forget to do that, anyway I have done right now, thank's again for the help.